# Pushed folder to github contains nothing

Tags: git, github

I have a directory,spring-boot-test, that I need to upload to github. The directory has child directories and files within them.

```
drwxrwxr-x. 23 jenkinsadmin jenkinsadmin 4096 Sep 19 02:33 spring-boot-test
```

When I push the directory, it shows it as a file in github or it shows there are no child directories under it.

```
git add .
git push origin master
```

Another try per comment:

```
[jenkinsadmin@localhost test]$ git add --all
[jenkinsadmin@localhost test]$ git commit -m "test"
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   spring-boot-test (modified content)

no changes added to commit

[jenkinsadmin@localhost test]$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

and I get `Everything up-to-date`, but if I check in github, it has folder symbol but contains nothing.

I do not want to drag and drop using GUI.
I am using git command on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I push the directory, it shows it as a file in github or it shows there are no child directories under it.

That means it shows a **gitlink**: a SHA1 reference to the root tree SHA1 of a subrepo.

First remove it from your index:

```
git rm --cached spring-boot-test
```

(no trailing `/`: you are removing a file-ish entry)

Then remove its `.git` subfolder (if you don't care about the history) of those files, then add, commit and push.

The alternative would be to reference `spring-boot-test` [as a submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). It would then show up on GitHub as a "file", but this time, cloning your repo would bring `spring-boot-test` content with it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to commit the files before trying to push them:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

git commit -m "some message" (do this after git add .)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add empty folder, see [Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F)

Comment: It is not empty. The folder has sub folders and files.

Comment: Try to check every folders with `git status`

Comment: I get this message, Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.  My local git folder has sub folders and files. However if I push it to github, I see the folder is empty in github.

Comment: Is it your own repository? and make sure you switch to the right branch on github

Comment: And you can see commits on github, is the file or folder added at the lastest commit?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the all the suggestions here. The local folder appeared to have hidden github files (.github).  I removed any hidden files related to git and github. I can see all the sub folders and files are populated in github now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit changes before pushing it to the remote repo:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Your commit"
git push <remote> <branch-name> 
e.g. git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

on the github when i see the contents of the folder it is empty but when i clone it has the data, this is a little annoying to me, I've tried removing .git folder but still no luck, or the arch is built like that.

here is my git repo : https://github.com/adithnaveen/SapientTraining2019Batch/tree/master/whelps%20code